# Why cant I drag and drop a Sprite in a Scriptable Objects inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

So I have a scriptable object that holds a public Image variable. And I want to drag an image to the inspector, but I'm not able to get it to work. I have changed the Texture Type to Sprite (2D and UI). I have tried to find people with similar problems but the only answer I can find is to change the Texture Type to sprite. And I need the Texture Type to be used for UI for ex Player HUD that shows cooldown on abilities.

Picture of Image Inspector

[image]

Picture of Scriptable object inspector

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image` is a class inherited from [UnityEngine.UI namespace](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.html). And to be shown requires a Canvas component.

You can create a prefab with an Image that contains your sprite in order to add to your scriptable object, then use `abiltyIcon.sprite` in order to recieve the original sprite when needed.

---

If you don't want to create a prefab then the solution would be using `Sprite` class as mentioned.

Just by doing the reverse path I've mentioned early. Instead of having an `Image` with a `Sprite` you would have a `Sprite` and add it to an empty `Image` on the code.

Considering you are using a scriptable object, check if this solution isn't better than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Texture" or "Sprite" instead of "Image" as type of "abilityIcon" in "FireBall.cs".